# Nested objects within arrays to insert and update simultaneously into many tables

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I'm sending in an object with nested arrays and objects within arrays. This procedure should update data in tables depending on if an ID exists, if not then it should insert into table. When executing this procedure it only updates the outer object(cases table) and the objects within the identifiers array that contain the caseIdentifierId. It won't create a new case identifier in the case_identifiers table, which it should do. The investigators and services arrays within the identifiers array should know they belong to that identifier so an "importId" has been added. Each identifier object has its own importId. The investigators and services that contain a "seqId" means that they have been created before, therefore they should be updated in table instead of inserted.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE cases_updateAll

@caseObj NVARCHAR(MAX)

/*
DECLARE @caseObj NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[
        {
          "caseId": 1010,
          "caseName": "Fruit",
          "identifiers": [
              {
                "caseIdentifierId": 1030,
                "importId": 2,
                "identifierName": "Apple",
                "investigators": [
                    {
                      "seqId": 50,
                      "importId": 2,
                      "investigatorId": 163,
                      "investigatorTypeCd": "LI"
                    },
                    {
                      "importId": 2,
                      "investigatorId": 178,
                      "investigatorTypeCd": "RV"
                    }
                ],
                "services": [
                    {
                      "importId": 2,
                      "serviceId": 115,
                      "serviceCatCd": "OTH",
                      "servicePrice": 2250
                    },
                    {
                      "importId": 2,
                      "serviceId": 110,
                      "serviceCatCd": "INTL",
                      "servicePrice": 900
                    }
                ]
              },
              {
                "importId": 3,
                "identifierName": "Orange",
                "investigators": [
                    {
                      "importId": 3,
                      "investigatorId": 139,
                      "investigatorTypeCd": "RV"
                    },
                    {
                      "importId": 3,
                      "investigatorId": 138,
                      "investigatorTypeCd": "SI"
                    }
                ],
                "services": [
                    {
                      "importId": 3,
                      "serviceId": 107,
                      "serviceCatCd": "DD",
                      "servicePrice": 44550
                    }
                ]
              }
          ]
        }
    ]';
 EXECUTE cases_updateAll @caseObj=@caseObj
*/

AS

DECLARE @importId INT
SET @importId = 1

BEGIN
```

---------- UPDATE cases TABLE ----------

```
WITH json_data as
(
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON(@caseObj) A
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(A.value)
    WITH
    (
        caseId INT,
        caseName NVARCHAR(500)
    )
)

UPDATE c 
SET
    date_modified = GETUTCDATE(),
    case_name = jd.caseName, 
    import_id = @importId
FROM
    cases AS c
    INNER JOIN json_data AS jd ON jd.caseId = c.case_id

WHERE case_id = jd.caseId
```

---------- UPDATE & INSERT INTO case_identifiers TABLE ----------

```
select B.*
INTO #tmpIdents
FROM OPENJSON(@caseObj)
WITH (
    identifiers NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
) AS caseIdents
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (caseIdents.identifiers)
WITH (
    caseIdentifierId INT,
    identifierName NVARCHAR(500),
    importId INT
) B;

WITH Acte AS
(
    SELECT c.*,ci.case_identifier_id AS case_ident_id
    FROM #tmpIdents c
    INNER JOIN case_identifiers ci ON c.importId=ci.import_id
)
MERGE case_identifiers AS Target
USING (SELECT * FROM Acte) AS SOURCE
ON Target.case_identifier_id = Source.caseIdentifierId
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    date_modified = GETUTCDATE(),
    identifier_name = Source.identifierName,
    import_id = Source.importId
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT(
    identifier_name,
    import_id
)
VALUES(
    Source.identifierName,
    Source.importId
);
```

---------- INSERT INTO case_to_case_identifier ----------

```
INSERT INTO case_to_case_identifier
(case_id, case_identifier_id)
SELECT c.case_id, ci.case_identifier_id
FROM #tmpIdents ti
INNER JOIN cases c ON c.import_id=1
INNER JOIN case_identifiers ci ON ci.import_id=ti.importId
```

---------- INSERT INTO case_identifier_to_investigator TABLE ----------

```
select C.*
INTO #tmpInvs
FROM OPENJSON(@caseObj)
WITH (
    identifiers NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
) AS caseIdents
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (caseIdents.identifiers)
WITH (
    investigators NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
) AS caseIdentInvs
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (caseIdentInvs.investigators)
WITH (
    investigatorId INT,
    investigatorTypeCd CHAR(5),
    importId INT,
    seqId INT
) C;

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT c.*,ci.case_identifier_id AS case_ident_id
    FROM #tmpInvs c
    INNER JOIN case_identifiers ci ON c.importId=ci.import_id
    INNER JOIN kdd_investigator_type ki ON c.investigatorTypeCd=ki.investigator_type_cd
)
MERGE case_identifier_to_investigator AS Target
USING (SELECT * FROM cte) AS SOURCE
ON Target.seq_id = Source.seqId
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    investigator_id = Source.investigatorId,
    investigator_type_cd = Source.investigatorTypeCd
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT(investigator_id, case_identifier_id, investigator_type_cd)
VALUES(Source.investigatorId, Source.case_ident_id, Source.investigatorTypeCd);
```

---------- INSERT INTO case_identifier_to_service TABLE ----------

```
select D.*
INTO #tmpServs
FROM OPENJSON(@caseObj)
WITH (
    [services] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
) AS caseIdentServs
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (caseIdentServs.[services])
WITH (
    serviceId INT,
    importId INT,
    seqId INT,
    servPrice DECIMAL
) D;

WITH Scte AS
(
    SELECT c.*,ci.case_identifier_id AS case_ident_id
    FROM #tmpServs c
    INNER JOIN case_identifiers ci ON c.importId=ci.import_id
)
MERGE case_identifier_to_service AS Target
USING (SELECT * FROM Scte) AS SOURCE
ON Target.seq_id = Source.seqId
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    service_id = Source.serviceId
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT(service_id, case_identifier_id, service_price)
VALUES(Source.serviceId, Source.case_ident_id, Source.servPrice);
```

---------- SET importId to NULL ----------

```
UPDATE case_identifiers SET import_id = null;
UPDATE cases SET import_id = null;

END
```

---------- TABLE DIAGRAMS ----------

```
Cases
+-------------+---------+
|  import_id  | case_id |
+-------------+---------+
| NULL        | 1008    |
| NULL        | 1009    |
| 1           | 1010    | <--- @importId sets this to 1
+-------------+---------+

TmpIdents (c)
+-------------+---------------+
|  import_id  | case_ident_id |
+-------------+---------------+
| 2           | 1030          |
| 3           | NULL          |
+-------------+---------------+

Case Identifiers (ci)
+-------------+---------------+
|  import_id  | case_ident_id |
+-------------+---------------+
| 2           | 1030          |
| 3           | NULL          | <--- will become 1040
+-------------+---------------+

Case to Case Identifiers
+-------------+--------------+---------------+--------+
|  import_id  |   case_id    | case_ident_id | seq_id |
+-------------+--------------+---------------+--------+
| 2           | 1010         | 1030          | 50     |
| 3           | 1010         | 1040          | 51     |
+-------------+--------------+---------------+--------+

Case Identifier to Investigator
+-------------+---------+--------------+---------------+--------+
|  import_id  | inv_id  | inv_type_cd  | case_ident_id | seq_id |
+-------------+---------+--------------+---------------+--------+
| 2           | 163     | LI           | 1030          | 64     |
| 2           | 178     | RV           | 1030          | 65     |
| 3           | 139     | RV           | 1040          | 66     |
| 3           | 138     | SI           | 1040          | 67     |
+-------------+---------+--------------+---------------+--------+

Case Identifier to Service
+-------------+---------+---------------+--------+
|  import_id  | serv_id | case_ident_id | seq_id |
+-------------+---------+---------------+--------+
| 2           | 115     | 1030          | 23     |
| 2           | 110     | 1030          | 24     |
| 3           | 107     | 1040          | 25     |
+-------------+---------+---------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes rather late, hopefully it is still helpful.

Your question is *TL;TR*, but I think I can point you an alternative approach, which makes live easier: Try to read the *whole lot* into a staging table and proceed from there:

```
DECLARE @caseObj NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[
    {
      "caseId": 1010,
      "caseName": "Fruit",
      "identifiers": [
          {
            "caseIdentifierId": 1030,
            "importId": 2,
            "identifierName": "Apple",
            "investigators": [
                {
                  "seqId": 50,
                  "importId": 2,
                  "investigatorId": 163,
                  "investigatorTypeCd": "LI"
                },
                {
                  "importId": 2,
                  "investigatorId": 178,
                  "investigatorTypeCd": "RV"
                }
            ],
            "services": [
                {
                  "importId": 2,
                  "serviceId": 115,
                  "serviceCatCd": "OTH",
                  "servicePrice": 2250
                },
                {
                  "importId": 2,
                  "serviceId": 110,
                  "serviceCatCd": "INTL",
                  "servicePrice": 900
                }
            ]
          },
          {
            "importId": 3,
            "identifierName": "Orange",
            "investigators": [
                {
                  "importId": 3,
                  "investigatorId": 139,
                  "investigatorTypeCd": "RV"
                },
                {
                  "importId": 3,
                  "investigatorId": 138,
                  "investigatorTypeCd": "SI"
                }
            ],
            "services": [
                {
                  "importId": 3,
                  "serviceId": 107,
                  "serviceCatCd": "DD",
                  "servicePrice": 44550
                }
            ]
          }
      ]
    }
]';
```

--The query will dive deeper and deeper by adding `APPLY OPENJSON` for any nested list
--The result is written into a physical table implicitly

```
SELECT A.caseId
      ,A.caseName
      ,identif.caseIdentifierId AS identif_caseIdentifier
      ,identif.importId AS identif_importId
      ,identif.identifierName AS identif_identifierName
      ,invest.seqId AS invest_seqId
      ,invest.importId AS invest_importId
      ,invest.investigatorId AS invest_investigatorId
      ,invest.investigatorTypeCd AS invest_investigatorTypeCd
      ,serv.importId AS serv_importId
      ,serv.serviceId AS serv_serviceId
      ,serv.serviceCatCd AS serv_serviceCatCd
      ,serv.servicePrice AS serv_servicePrice
INTO #tmpStagingTable
FROM OPENJSON(@caseObj)
WITH(caseId INT, caseName NVARCHAR(200)
    ,identifiers NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) A
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(A.identifiers)
WITH(caseIdentifierId INT, importId INT, identifierName NVARCHAR(200)
    ,investigators NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
    ,[services] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) identif
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(identif.investigators)
WITH(seqId INT, importId INT, investigatorId INT, investigatorTypeCd NVARCHAR(100)) invest
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(identif.[services])
WITH(importId INT,serviceId INT,serviceCatCd NVARCHAR(100),servicePrice DECIMAL(10,4)) serv;
```

--Check out the result

```
SELECT * FROM #tmpStagingTable;

+--------+----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+---------------+----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| caseId | caseName | identif_caseIdentifier | identif_importId | identif_identifierName | invest_seqId | invest_importId | invest_investigatorId | invest_investigatorTypeCd | serv_importId | serv_serviceId | serv_serviceCatCd | serv_servicePrice |
+--------+----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+---------------+----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 1010   | Fruit    | 1030                   | 2                | Apple                  | 50           | 2               | 163                   | LI                        | 2             | 115            | OTH               | 2250.0000         |
+--------+----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+---------------+----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 1010   | Fruit    | 1030                   | 2                | Apple                  | 50           | 2               | 163                   | LI                        | 2             | 110            | INTL              | 900.0000          |
+--------+----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+---------------+----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 1010   | Fruit    | 1030                   | 2                | Apple                  | NULL         | 2               | 178                   | RV                        | 2             | 115            | OTH               | 2250.0000         |
+--------+----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+---------------+----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 1010   | Fruit    | 1030                   | 2                | Apple                  | NULL         | 2               | 178                   | RV                        | 2             | 110            | INTL              | 900.0000          |
+--------+----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+---------------+----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 1010   | Fruit    | NULL                   | 3                | Orange                 | NULL         | 3               | 139                   | RV                        | 3             | 107            | DD                | 44550.0000        |
+--------+----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+---------------+----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 1010   | Fruit    | NULL                   | 3                | Orange                 | NULL         | 3               | 138                   | SI                        | 3             | 107            | DD                | 44550.0000        |
+--------+----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+---------------+----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

From this you can proceed. There are multiple approaches:

- use several `MERGE` statements into all your tables by selecting with `GROUP BY`.
- use some kind of *self-created-merge* by checking for existance and insert or update whatever needed.
- add column(s) to the staging table and do an update there with the ids found in the target. Then use this id for the action

With actions like this I'd recommend to always put a staging step in between...